# How to check what file is uploaded

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I wanna check the file before it is uploaded to PhpMyAdmin. The only file types I wanna add to my database are PDF, DOC and DOCX. I have checked on the internet for the solution but I really can't find any. I hope you guys can help me with this.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
// CONNECTIE MAKEN MET DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// CHECK IF SUBMIT IS CLICKED
// CONTROLEER OF SUBMIT IS GEKLIKT
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$filetmp = $_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"];
$filename = $_FILES["cv"]["name"];
$filetype = $_FILES["cv"]["type"];
$filepath = "files/".$filename;

move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);


// INSERT VALUES IN THE DATABASE
// VOEG WAARDES TOE IN DE DATABASE
$sql = "INSERT INTO cv (cv_name,cv_path,cv_type) VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
// INSERT cv_id IN person_id
// VOEG cv_id TOE IN person_id
$cv = $conn->insert_id;
?>
```

Comment: and do you feel that the HTML form being omitted from the question irrelevant? check for errors, you're not doing that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php check file extension in upload form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456113/php-check-file-extension-in-upload-form)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [is_uploaded_file():](http://[is_uploaded_file():][1]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo 'No upload';
}
```

From the docs: Returns TRUE if the file named by:

> filename was uploaded via HTTP POST. This is useful to help ensure
>   that a malicious user hasn't tried to trick the script into working on
>   files upon which it should not be working--for instance, /etc/passwd.
>
> This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that
>   anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the
>   user, or even to other users on the same system. EDIT: I'm using this
>   in my FileUpload class, in case it helps:

```
public function fileUploaded()
{
    if(empty($_FILES)) {
        return false;       
    } 
    $this->file = $_FILES[$this->formField];
    if(!file_exists($this->file['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($this->file['tmp_name'])){
        $this->errors['FileNotExists'] = true;
        return false;
    }   
    return true;
}
```