# why in_array() function does not work with variable

Tags: php, function

Hello I'm having issue with php in_array function.
I want to check the uploaded files extension whether it meets my requirement or not, and for that I'm using following code.

```
$imgExtension = explode(".",$imageName);
$allowed_extension = array("png","jpg","jpeg","gif");
echo $end = end($imgExtension);

if(in_array(trim($end),$allowed_extension)){
    echo "File is correct";

}else{
    echo "File is incorrect";

}
```

The issue that I'm facing is the in_array function, the uploaded file's extension is jpg,png and jpeg, yet the in_array condition turns false, don't know why...

but instead of $end variable, if I pass any string like "jpg" or "png" in in_array functions parameter, then it works...

Comment: `var_dump($end);` verify it contains what you think before going into `in_array`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php check file extension in upload form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456113/php-check-file-extension-in-upload-form)

Comment: This seems to be working fine for me. [See here](https://3v4l.org/HTvlt)

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456113/php-check-file-extension-in-upload-form

Comment: Since your array of file extensions are all lower case you need to make sure that the extension of the uploaded files is also all lower case too.